# PhD applications and explaining poor results

Tags: phd, application

I had a couple of bouts of depression during my masters degree which resulted in very bad grades. Is it a good or bad idea to mention this in PhD applications to explain my grades?

Comment: Duplicate of https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/32112/how-much-detail-about-mental-health-issues-should-one-include-in-special-circum?rq=1

Answer (score -1):

First of all, I hope you are doing fine now, have recovered from depression, or are on the way to recovery!

I believe that there is no need to give insight in your mental health to a possible future employer. I would advise you to generally speak about „health conditions“ instead of disclosing your mental state, if you feel the need to explain your grades.